# Where is Fedora 17's boot.iso?

Tags: fedora

I am attempting to install Fedora 17 on a netbook, and according to the documentation on http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/17/html/Installation_Guide/ch-new-users.html, in order to do this you should obtain the boot.iso file at fedora/linux/releases/17/Fedora/arch/os/images/boot.iso

Well, I attempted to go there and I am getting "page not found" errors. Worse, while there are lots of different links to different files and formats on Fedora's website, there is apparently no link to the boot.iso file!

Can someone please tell me where this ISO file is??? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're supposed to replace `arch` with the appropriate architecture, for example `i386` or `x86_64`, so you want something like:

http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/17/Fedora/i386/os/images/boot.iso

or:

http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/17/Fedora/x86_64/os/images/boot.iso

Comment: OOPS. I did not realize this. Thanks...